# What is the correct way to read db data async?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite, async-await

could you please be so kind to point me to the mistake why I have the following code run synchronously and block UI during async request to DB? Thanks in advance.

My ViewModel:

```
public virtual bool MerchantsLoading { get; set; }
public virtual ObservableCollectionCore<Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }

public MerchantViewModel { //constructor
    MerchantsLoading = true;
    Merchants = SQLite.GetMerchants().Result;
    SQLite.GetMerchants().ContinueWith(task => MerchantsLoading =     false);
}
```

My View:

```
...
<dxg:GridControl ShowLoadingPanel="{Binding MerchantsLoading}" ItemsSource="{Binding Merchants}".../>
...
```

SQLite.GetMerchants():

```
public static async Task<ObservableCollectionCore<Merchant>> GetMerchants()
{
    SQLiteConnection SqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection(MerchantDB);
    var Merchants = new ObservableCollectionCore<Merchant.Merchant>();
    try
    {
        await SqlConnection.OpenAsync();
        SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand("select * from merchant", SqlConnection);
        DbDataReader myReader = await myCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            Merchants.Add(new Merchant.Merchant
            {
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["ID"]),
                Name = Convert.ToString(myReader["Name"])
            });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new LogMessage { Message = "Ошибка в процедуре GetMerchants" });
        Messenger.Default.Send(new LogMessage { Message = ex.ToString() });
    }
    finally
    {
        SqlConnection.Close();
    }
    return Merchants;
}
```

I've added new function which is fired on UserControl.Loaded event, but UI is still blocked (viewmodel constructor is now empty):

```
public async void Loaded()
{
    MerchantsLoading = true;
    Merchants = await SQLite.GetMerchants();
    await SQLite.GetMerchants().ContinueWith(task => MerchantsLoading = false);
}
```

Loaded event fired by EventToCommand of DevExpress MVVM Framework:

```
<UserControl xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm" xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:ORBKWorker.Merchant"
         xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:ORBKWorker.Helpers"
         xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
         xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
         xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol"
         x:Class="ORBKWorker.Merchant.MerchantView"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         DataContext="{dxmvvm:ViewModelSource Type={x:Type ViewModels:MerchantViewModel}}"
         d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1920">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Helpers:IntToEmailType x:Key="IntToEmailType"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <dxmvvm:EventToCommand EventName="Loaded" Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}"/>
</dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
<Grid>...
```

Finally decided to do it with BackgroundWorker:

```
    public void GetMerchants()
    {
        MerchantsLoading = true;
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += (sender, args) => Merchants = SQLite.GetMerchants();
        bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) => MerchantsLoading = false;
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: To my knowledge, your awaiting function should return Task, that is await should be used with a function return a Task. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Answer (score 3):

You are blocking your thread by calling `Result` on the `Task` here:

```
Merchants = SQLite.GetMerchants().Result;
```

Instead you should await the `Task`. Unfortunately you can't make a constructor `async`, so you have to move that code to an event handler, maybe `Loaded` or something, and make that `async`.

Comment: Added information on the question:
Added new function and cleared constructor.

Comment: So where is `Window_Loaded`?

Comment: Added info to question.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, the SQLite asynchronous methods are not actually asynchronous. So, you'll need to use a background thread like `Task.Run`.

You *can* do it in the `Loaded` event:

```
public async void Loaded()
{
  MerchantsLoading = true;
  Merchants = await Task.Run(() => SQLite.GetMerchants());
  MerchantsLoading = false;
}
```

However, I think it would be cleaner to use [my `NotifyTask<T>` type](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.Mvvm.Async/1.0.0-eta-01/netstandard1.0/doc/Nito.Mvvm.NotifyTask'1):

```
public virtual NotifyTask<ObservableCollectionCore<Merchant>> Merchants { get; set; }

public MerchantViewModel()
{
  Merchants = NotifyTask.Create(Task.Run(() => SQLite.GetMerchants()));
}
```

with view:

```
<dxg:GridControl ShowLoadingPanel="{Binding Merchants.IsNotCompleted}" ItemsSource="{Binding Merchants.Result}" .../>
```